# Target has transitive dependencies that include statically linked binaries in podspec

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, podspec, google-cast-sdk

I have a problem when I try to update google-cast-sdk pod in the podspec file my Pod library project.

In this podspec file I have:

```
s.dependency 'google-cast-sdk', '= 4.2.0'
```

This version works fine, but I need update the library to the last version so I modified this line to:

```
s.dependency 'google-cast-sdk'
```

But when I execute the pod install I get the following error:

> [!] The 'Pods-XXXPlay_Example' target has transitive dependencies that
> include statically linked binaries:
> (/Users/juanfran/code/xxxx-play-ios/Example/Pods/google-cast-sdk/GoogleCastSDK-ios-4.4.7_static/GoogleCast.framework)

Could you help me with this problem, please?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Hi did you solve it? I have the same problem

Comment: hi @ch271828n I still have the problem. I am trying to do the manual setup that Google suggests here: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ios_sender#manual_setup but I cannot find the XCode sections of the screenshots that appear. I created the following case to expose this question: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/161814397 
Have you tried to do the manual setup?